# Should you insert a space between the second hyphen and the next word?

Tags: punctuation, suspended-hyphen

Here's a sample sentence:

> The waiters scurried back and forth with drink- and snack- laden trays.

Or is there another way to punctuate this?

Comment: If you wouldn't insert a space in a single hyphenated word, why would you insert one in this case?

Comment: @KateBunting: Uh ... symmetry? ... I don't know.

Comment: You write the hyphenated word in the normal way, as shown in various examples in the second 'duplicate'.